# Razor page not callling correct controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I'm new to Razor pages and need some help.

I have a .CSHTML file which specifies a page. This page contains a couple of checkboxes for the user to check or uncheck. The page sets the states of these checkboxes according to the viewmodel they are using. However, when I hit the save button, the application crashes saying it cannot find any method that takes 0 arguments. How do I make it return the viewmodel to my save method below? Some filepaths are omitted because of privacy reasons.

I've tried Using form (as in the example) and Setting handler on button which caused it to navigate to non existing link. Intellisene do find the controller and the method, so they are visible.

**My View:**

```
@model Models.MenuItemsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Menus";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4">@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    <p>here you can set values</p>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MenuItems", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h2>Menus</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Schedule)
                </td>
                <td> @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Schedule, new { @checked = Model.Schedule }) </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FAQ)
                </td>
                <td> @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.FAQ, new { @checked = Model.FAQ }) </td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Save these values" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  />
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Models;

namespace Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("menuItems")]
    [Authorize(Roles = LoginController)]
    public class MenuItemsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppContext context = new AppContext();

        [Route("")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var menuItems = context.MenuItems.SingleOrDefault();
            return View(new MenuItemsViewModel(menuItems));
        }

        [HttpPost] //I want to call this method when I press save!
        public ActionResult Save(MenuItemsViewModel model)
        {
            var menuItems = context.MenuItems.SingleOrDefault();

            if (menuItems == null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Something went wrong";
            }

            model.UpdateFromViewModel(menuItems);

            ViewBag.Message = "Information saved";
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");}
    }
}
```

I want the Viewmodel to be updated and sent in a call to the Save method so it can save it to the database.

Comment: Not sure but maybe it can be a matter of case sensitivity. You have `MenuItems` in the `cshtml` file and `menuItems` in the controller attribute.

Comment: You can also try to add `[Route("Save")]` above the `public ActionResult Save` method

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation why you can not run Save action after you click the button on the client side is because you did not add the

```
    //enable attribute routing
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

to your RouteConfig.cs file. It should look like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //enable attribute routing
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the MapMvcAttributeRoutes() to RouteConfig in Appdata folder

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

then change menuItem controller like  the image below

```
    [RoutePrefix("menuItems")]
public class MenuItemController : Controller
{
    // GET: MenuItem
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost] 
    [Route("Save")] // put the route attribuate 
    public ActionResult Save(MenuItemsViewModel model)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Information saved";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have the RouteConfig. I tried adding the Route("Save") attribute but it didn't work. I have tried putting breakpoints in the Index method and it does stop there so that method is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it. The solution was to add an empty constructor for the Viewmodel.